# Why does RestSharp throw an error when deserializing a boolean response?

Tags: restsharp

When I make a request in RestSharp like so:

```
var response = client.Execute<bool>(request);
```

I get the following error:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."
```

This is complete HTTP response, per Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2013 15:09:14 GMT
Content-Length: 5

false
```

It appears that everything is kosher with the response, so what gives?

Also, if I'm doing something stupid with my WebAPI Controller by returning a simple value instead of an object and that would fix my problem, feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RestSharp will only deserialise valid json. `false` is not valid json (according to RFC-4627). The server will need to return something like the following at the least:

```
{ "foo": false }
```

And you'll need a class like to following to deserialize to:

```
public class BooleanResponse
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh.  Right.  That makes sense.  My bad.

Comment: FYI, that's exactly what you're supposed to return "Json(true)" from a RemoteValidationAttribute.  Surprised that MSFT has us return invalid JSON in their own example.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Slightly incorrect. `false` *is* actually valid JSON but I don't think it's valid to return it alone as `application/json` . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569221/did-the-publication-of-ecma-404-affect-the-validity-of-json-texts-such-as-2-or and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json